# Site not indexed after moving site from WordPress to Magento

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, sitemap, googlebot, magento

I moved a site from WordPress to Magento. But now Google webmaster does not index the site. I have submitted the sitemap, but it remains pending. I also have a `robots.txt` file which has the following content

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

Is there anything I have to do after moving from WordPress to Magento?

**Edit :**

I feel the problem is with robots.txt because in my crawl errors page in google search console, robots.txt fetch shows an orange status instead of a green tick. Under that tab, it shows a message 'Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file'. But when I go to mydomain.com/robots.txt, it displays my robots.txt file.

,I have tried Fetch as google in search console. It fetches completely when I use 'fetch' and partially when I use 'fetch and render'.

Comment: What about the URL structure? Has that changed? Are you 301 redirecting all the old URLs to the new? It would be preferable to use `Disallow:` (without any URL-path) instead of `Allow: /` (but that shouldn't make any difference to Google).

Comment: @w3dk , There is a slight change in URL structure in my website, but I don't have problem if the old url shows 'page not found'. (if that's what you were asking).I feel the problem is with robots.txt because in my crawl errors page in google search console, robots.txt fetch shows an orange status instead of a green tick. Under that tab, it shows a message 'Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file'. But when I go to mydomain.com/robots.txt, it displays my robots.txt file.

Comment: *Google couldn't crawl your site because we were unable to access your site's robots.txt file.* That just may be a temporary network error. Have you tried a Fetch as Google in Search Console? Check that to make sure G can see your home page at least.

Comment: @closetnoc ,I have tried Fetch as google in search console. It fetches completely when I use 'fetch' and partially when I use 'fetch and render'.

Comment: It is not uncommon that Google has network troubles accessing a site. This would of course effect being able to access the robots.txt. Generally, a few days later, all will work fine. I would be more concerned that *rendering* does not give you what you expect. You can also check your log files for errors. If you do a fetch, you can check your log file, however, it can take a while for the entry to appear because of caching. So keep that in mind. If G can access your site, then you are okay. Do not worry about it.

Comment: @closetnoc, Thanks for your comment.I'll wait for a couple of days and hope everything is fine.Regarding the rendering errors, I am a fresher webmaster and still don't have much idea on it. I get 'not found' and 'temporarily unreachable' error for few URLs(.jpg, .js and .css files). It would be great if you can give me any link where I can learn more about it. Thanks

Comment: There is no link I can think of to help you. As many of your page resources should be on your site as possible. If not appropriate, then you will want these other sites to be reliable at least. The Internet uses TCP/IP which is not a guaranteed delivery protocol. Even with re-try, things can go wonky from time to time even for Google.

Comment: Did you solve this? If not, I have a few questions:
- How many sitemaps do you usually handle?
- Does this happen in only on a subdomain or all the subdomains of your core domain? (freetips.site)?
- How many pages approx are you trying to index?

Comment: @mayrop . It had started to index after few days. Anyway, Now I have changed my site back to wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

As W3dk says in the comments, a more correct robots.txt file would be:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:

sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap.xml
```

But your biggest problem is most likely that you didn't redirect your old URLs to your new ones.   You say:

> There is a slight change in URL structure in my website, but I don't have problem if the old url shows 'page not found'.

Google is going to index pages right away if you redirect the old URLs to the new ones.    Making this kind of change without redirects kills your inbound link profile, and Google's trust in your site.   It may take months or years for your site to get indexed and enjoy rankings as good as it used to have.   Implement the redirects.